How can I resolve this psycopg.errors.SyntaxError in UNNEST call?
Update:
Found this section of documentation. Code changes are below, sample query output added.
The sample code below generates a psycopg.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "[".  LINE 4: ... unnest(Composed([Identifie... with a carat pointing to the bracket just before the word Identifier.
The real version of the sample function uses query_columns for fields to query and dynamic CTE table names.  For example, my_cte_table_{query_column}.
I've read the documentation and tried to find some related questions but am stuck.
What should I try to resolve this error and use the query columns in CTE table names?
import psycopg
from psycopg.sql import Identifier, SQL

def example(query_columns, table):
        """
        Use for SO question
        """
        table = psycopg.sql.Identifier(table)
        my_unnest_array = 
        psycopg.sql.SQL(',').join(list([psycopg.sql.Identifier(col) for col in query_columns]))
                my_unnest_array = ','.join(query_columns)
                sql_statement = f"""
                                with some_data as -- Pull data & get it into one column
                                                                (SELECT 
                                                                    unnest(array[{my_unnest_array}])::numeric as x
                                                                    from {table}
                                                                )
                                ,more_data as  ( select 
                                                         min(x) as min_x
                                                        ,max(x) as max_x
                                                        from some_data
                                                                )
                                """
                sql_statement = sql_statement + ' select * from more_data'
                return sql_statement
    
    _sql = ss.example(query_columns=['obs1'], table='pistons')
    named_variables_for_sql = {'obs1': 'obs1','table': 'pistons'}
    # create db connection, get connection and cursor object
    db_connection_cursor = db_connection_cursor_object()
    # execute query
    db_connection_cursor['cursor'].execute(_sql, named_variables=named_variables_for_sql)
    my_data = db_connection_cursor['cursor'].fetchall()

The generated SQL is this:
            with some_data as -- Pull data & get it into one column
                                            (SELECT 
                                                unnest(Composed([Identifier('obs1')]))::numeric as x
                                                --unnest(array[Composed([Identifier('obs1')])])::numeric as x
                                                from Identifier('z_piston_rings')
                                            )
            ,more_data as  ( select 
                                     min(x) as min_x
                                    ,max(x) as max_x
                                    from some_data
                                            )
             select * from more_data


Why the downvote?  What could I do better?

I didn't dv, but you could, for example, show us an example of the generated final query. You could also execute it in the psql console, which might provide more information about the location of the error.

@snakecharmerb updated question per your helpful feedback.

Do you need to do my_unnest_array.as_string(db_connection) to stringify the SQL object before injecting ti into the sql_statement string?

@snakecharmerb you pointed me in the right direction.  Rather than downvote and move on you helped.  You are the kind of person that makes SO amazing.  The final trick was:     table = Composable.as_string(psycopg.sql.Identifier(table))     my_unnest_array = (',').join([Composable.as_string(psycopg.sql.Identifier(col)) for col in query_columns])
Post as answer and I'll accept?

Feel free to self-answer
